# $\mathbb{Q}$ dense in $\mathbb{R}$ does also $\mathbb{Q^2}$ dense in $\mathbb{R^2}$?

Tags: real-numbers, rational-numbers

It is well known that density of Rational numbers in Real numbers a well known result which means that there exist infinity many rational numbers between two arbitrary real numbers , Now I ask simply is  $\mathbb{Q^2}$ also dense in $\mathbb{R^2}$? ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is true, and follows almost immediately from the density of $\mathbb{Q}$ in $\mathbb{R}$.  For instance, given any open rectangle $(a,b) \times (c,d)$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$, by the density of $\mathbb{Q}$ in $\mathbb{R}$ you can find rationals $p \in (a,b)$ and $q \in (c,d)$.  Now $(p,q)$ is a point of $\mathbb{Q}^2$ that is in the given rectangle.

Comment: Thanks , What about density of Q^n in R^n for n > 2 ? is this also hold

Comment: @zeraouliarafik: Yes, and with the same proof again.